# Filtering peaks of a H-bridge driving an electromagnet?

Tags: h-bridge, passive-filter, electromagnet

I'm driving an electromagnet (56.5Ω, 59mH) with an H-bridge composed by N-Type MOSFETs ([SiHFR120](https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/427/sihfr120-1768752.pdf)) and half-bridge drivers ([2EDL05I06PF](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/196/Infineon_2EDL05x06xx_DataSheet_v03_02_EN-1225330.pdf)). VDD is 80V.

Everything works fine excepting the huge current peaks which I'm not able to filter.

Strategies that I used to filter the peaks are:

1. I placed two 10uF capacitors in parallel to the bridge. The energy stored by the electromagnet is 60mJ and I calculated the required capacitance as 18.75uF.
2. I drive the bottom MOSFETs either full on or off, allowing for a current path when the upper MOSFETs switch off. E.g I drive Q1 with a PWM signal while Q4 is on. Q2-Q3 are obviously off in this case.
3. I used a RC snubber circuit (16uF and 1,2kΩ) in parallel to the electromagnet with no noticeable peak attenuation.

As you can see on the images below, the peaks are around -3.8A and 3.2A (0.1Ω shunt). The oscillation frequency is around 55.5MHz, driving frequency is 62kHz.

I'm probing on:

- channel 1 (blue) the common point between D1 and R5.
- channel 2 (yellow) the shunt (Vcurr).

I'm using no differential probe, so, both channels are referenced to GND/Earth.

In the situation where the peaks occur I'm only driving the electromagnet in one direction. I mean with this Q2-Q3 off, Q4 fully on and Q1 driven with a PWM at 62kHz.

The application of the circuit consists in creating repulsion or attraction with the electromagnet, both for a period longer than 2-3 seconds. There is therefore no fast switching in current direction. The idea is just to be able to control the current through the electromagnet and doing so, the force exerted (to other permanent magnet).

[image: Circuit design zoom]

[image: Circuit design]

[image: Oscilloscope 1]

[image: Oscilloscope 2]

Comment: A better quality circuit image is needed.  Data sheet links to the MOSFETs and drivers are also needed. Your oscilloscope probing method also needs to be shown. Please state what operating frequency you are using (I don't believe 55.5 MHz).

Comment: Show PCB/wiring layout (photo), including how you're probing.

Comment: Looks like shoot-through, do you have enough dead-time? The gate driver seems to follow a slow turn-on, fast turn-off, but 200 \$\Omega\$ might be a bit too much, while the 10 \$\Omega\$ could be omitted (if the diode and the driver can handle it). And the Schottkys might be not only redundant but, also a cause for the spikes.

Comment: I added new info and a more clear image of the circuit. 
@aconcernedcitizen I will try with a lower resistance for the on event. But this should not affect the peaks right (damping them)?
The Schottky diodes are there to protect the MOSFETs. On one side against high voltage and on the other side against the high current peaks as they allow more current to flow as the internal ones.
I had the same problem with the peaks before I placed the diodes, I can't see therefore a problem there.

Comment: An electromagnet that's designed for on/off operation may not be kind to a 60kHz driving circuit.  If you have the means, you may want to check to see what it's impedance is up to 1MHz or so.  If you have enough channels on your scope, it would be useful to probe the gate voltages of both FETs on one side of the bridge, your current, and the voltage on that side of the bridge -- it may show if you're setting yourself up for shoot-through.

Comment: In the situation where the peaks occur I'm only driving the electromagnet in one direction. I mean with this Q2-Q3 off, Q4 fully on and Q1 driven with a PWM at 62kHz.
During the measurement there was no change in direction of the current. I suppose that there is therefore no chance of shoot-through.

Comment: +1 @TimWilliams first we need to be sure the probe isn't picking up magnetic field, or other problems. So make sure to use the tiny ground clip on 10x probe, or solder 50R terminated coax right on R9. I assume R9 is SMD, because if it is not (or worse, wirewound) then the sharp di/dt at switching will make a voltage spike across it due to its inductance. Also need to see layout. You can check for shoot through by probing the supply voltage on the caps. If there is a sharp downwards voltage spike at switching that hints of shoot through.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The peaks were caused by the magnetic field the probe was picking during the current measurements as well suggested in the comments.
I connected the shunt to a op amp in a non-inverting configuration to have a resolution of 1V/A and the peaks are now in a more acceptable range.

[image]